# gsoap memory leak C applications

Tags: gsoap

We are using gsoap for C client and server webservices implemented for blackfin running Linux.

We don't use any malloc in the application. But we see memory usage climbs over time. We are using soap_end to do a cleanup at the end of the call. But when the calls are invoked repeatedly memory usage slowly increasing, may be because of memory fragmentation. This is also impacting performance of the system

What's the preferred usage of gsoap where soap_malloc is not used much. For eg: If we use static arrays etc will it help?

Thanks,

nkr

Answer (score 5):

I would not recommend using static data, there is no need for that.

To debug memory use, compile all your sources files with `-DDEBUG`. When you run your application you will see three files:

- `SENT.log` the messages sent
- `RECV.log` the messages received
- `TEST.log` the debug log

The `TEST.log` is useful to check on messaging issues.

The other valuable information produced at runtime are error messages related to memory leaks or heap memory that is damaged (e.g. overruns) in your code. It is unlikely these will happen in the gSOAP engine, but better check.

To ensure proper allocation and deallocation of managed data:

```
soap_destroy(soap);
soap_end(soap);
```

I am using the auto-generated functions to allocate managed data:

```
SomeClass *obj = soap_new_SomeClass(soap);
```

and sporadically use `soap_malloc` for raw managed allocation, or to allocate an array of pointers, or a C string:

```
const char *s = soap_malloc(soap, 100);
```

but better is to allocate strings with:

```
std::string *s = soap_new_std__string(soap);
```

and arrays can be allocated with the second parameter, e.g. an array of 10 strings:

```
std::string *s = soap_new_std__string(soap, 10);
```

All managed allocations are deleted with `soap_destroy()` followed by `soap_end()`. After that, you can start allocating again and delete again, etc.

If you want to preserve data that otherwise gets deleted with these calls, use:

```
soap_unlink(soap, obj);
```

Now `obj` can be removed later with `delete obj`. But be aware that all pointer members in `obj` that point to managed data have become invalid after `soap_destroy()` and `soap_end()`. So you may have to invoke `soap_unlink()` on these members or risk dangling pointers.

A new cool feature of gSOAP is to generate deep copy and delete function for any data structures automatically, which saves a HUGE amount of coding time:

```
SomeClass *otherobj = soap_dup_SomeClass(NULL, obj);
```

This duplicates `obj` to unmanaged heap space. This is a deep copy that checks for cycles in the object graph and removes such cycles to avoid deletion issues. You can also duplicate the whole (cyclic) managed object to another context by using `soap` instead of NULL for the first argument of `soap_dup_SomeClass`.

To deep delete:

```
 soap_del_SomeClass(obj);
```

This deletes `obj` but also the data pointed to by its members, and so on.

To use the `soap_dup_X` and `soap_del_X` functions use soapcpp2 with options `-Ec` and `-Ed`, respectively.

In principle, static and stack-allocated data can be serialized just as well. But consider using the managed heap instead.

Hope this helps.